# Page gets too height in Webview

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

Hi i have developed a web page in jQueryMobile.My Problem is, the page height seems too many large when i navigate from one page to another in WebView.Also note that the navigated page height is approximately same as the previous page height.What is the problem. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

What are the metatags that you have added to your jqm page? Try this in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,  maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Adjust min and max value if you would like to include zoom. Then you will also have to add those zoom features to your webview.